# XML foreach SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, curl, soap

I would like to read all the values in the `<areaCalda>` tag. I tried this way but it does not work.

this my xml:

```
<soap:....>
<listaStatoPS xmlns="http://stato.ps.ws.model.rc.nec">

<StatoPSWS>
<anagraficaPS>...</anagraficaPS>
<esitoRichiesta>...</esitoRichiesta>
<statoPS>
<areePS>
<AreaPS><areaCalda>true</areaCalda></AreaPS>
<AreaPS><areaCalda>false</areaCalda></AreaPS>
<AreaPS><areaCalda>false</areaCalda></AreaPS>
<AreaPS><areaCalda>true</areaCalda></AreaPS>
<AreaPS><areaCalda>true</areaCalda></AreaPS>
</areePS>
</statoPS>
</StatoPSWS>

<StatoPSWS>
<anagraficaPS>...</anagraficaPS>
<esitoRichiesta>...</esitoRichiesta>
<statoPS>
<areePS>
<AreaPS><areaCalda>false</areaCalda></AreaPS>
<AreaPS><areaCalda>false</areaCalda></AreaPS>
<AreaPS><areaCalda>false</areaCalda></AreaPS>
<AreaPS><areaCalda>true</areaCalda></AreaPS>
<AreaPS><areaCalda>false</areaCalda></AreaPS>
</areePS>
</statoPS>
</StatoPSWS>

</listaStatoPS>
<uuid xmlns="http://...">...</uuid>
</ns1:out>
</ns1:getStatoPSResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

my script: `foreach ($sxe->xpath('//listaStatoPS:StatoPSWS')` it's OK!

```
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$sxe->registerXPathNamespace('listaStatoPS', 'http://stato.ps.ws.model.rc.nec');
foreach ($sxe->xpath('//listaStatoPS:StatoPSWS') as $item) // this WORK!
{


    $data->registerXPathNamespace('listaStatoPS', 'http://stato.ps.ws.model.rc.nec');
    $el2 = $data->xpath('//listaStatoPS:StatoPSWS:areePS:AreaPS'); 

    foreach ($el2 as $val) // not work!
    {
    ...
    }



}
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you only read the  `areaCalda` values, then you can use something like this.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents("test.xml"));
foreach ($xml->xpath("//areaCalda") as $item){
    var_dump($item);
}
```

And don´t use for the next path `:` , you must use `/`

```
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$sxe->registerXPathNamespace('listaStatoPS', 'http://stato.ps.ws.model.rc.nec');
foreach ($sxe->xpath('//listaStatoPS/StatoPSWS') as $item) 
{
    $data->registerXPathNamespace('listaStatoPS', 'http://stato.ps.ws.model.rc.nec');
    $el2 = $item->xpath('//statoPS/areePS/AreaPS/areaCalda'); 

    foreach ($el2 as $val) 
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

And it should work